# Do I need to transform NAD 1983 CORS96 data to a NAD 1983 data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I'm working in ArcMap 10.8. The data and the data frame are both technically in StatePlane systems (e.g. NAD_1983_CORS96_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Ft_US and NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Ft_US) but I'm not sure if that changes things. Does one need to transform this data to fit the data frame accurately? And if so, what specific transformation do you use? I'm not seeing an option in ArcMap that looks correct.

I'm not a GIS specialist by training, just learning on the job. If anyone knows of any resources that allow you to look up specific coordinate systems and if they need to be transformed that would be a great help. Googling often raises more questions than it answers in these cases.

Comment: This is a good question for @mkennedy.

Comment: Use [NCAT](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/) to check for differences between Datums.

Comment: @Pointdump NCAT does not provide NAD 1983 CORS96 as one of its input or output reference frames. Which is confusing to me since it allows every other re-adjustment to the NAD 1983 datum as an option. CORS96 is conspicuously absent.

Comment: Sorry about the delay @carya. I didn't get the notification that GBG tried to make.

Answer (score 1):

NAD 1983 (CORS96) is functionally close to NAD 1983 HARN. If I understand correctly, CORS96 was somewhat of a re-adjustment of the CORS control network but not of the entire control network and never became an official re-adjustment.

To be as geodetically correct as possible, yes, you should convert the data, redefined as NAD 1983 HARN, to NAD 1983. To do so, you should install the ArcGIS Coordinate Systems Data setup (if you don't have it already) for 10.8.0 or 10.8.1. This setup includes the NADCON5 files.

Here's where this gets tricky. A lot of data out there is labelled as NAD 1983, but really isn't. The "NAD 1983" definition should refer to data in the original NAD 1983 (1986) realization. However, many people have just kept adding or updating features to "NAD 1983"-defined data, even though the new coordinates are referenced to a later realization like HARN, CORS96, NSRS2007, or 2011. If the dataset's accuracy is a meter or worse, it doesn't matter. If it's supposed to cm-level (maybe even decimeter) accuracy or better, then it would matter.

So, if you add both layers to a data frame, make sure no transformation is set and see how they line up. Next make a copy of the CORS96 data, redefine it as HARN, and do the same thing. How does it line up now? Once it's in HARN, you set a transformation between NAD 1983 and HARN and see if that improves the overlay of the layers.

Disclosure: I work for Esri, focusing on coordinate reference systems and transformations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I've been very confused about working with data from all these realizations while doing my own research, and it's nice to see it described all at once. Especially the bit about how data labeled as NAD83 might actually be collected while referenced to newer versions of that datum.

One question- at the end of your comment you say to "add both layers to a data frame." I only have the one layer of data- are you referring to my original data plus a transformation/redefinition of it? I'm not sure how I'd be able to glean which one was the right definition.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had existing data that you wanted to match. If not, you could just set the data's coordinate system to the data frame's.